# Why does LWP fail on OS X but not on my Windows 10?

Tags: perl, get, lwp

I tried getstore() and get() on (1) PC/Windows 10 with perl 5.14.2 and (2) Mac/OS X 10.11.6 with perl 5.18.2.

Some status codes produced by getstore are as follows: 200 is a good URL, 500 is "server failed to deliver".
Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;

print "\nThe below is successful on both Windows 10 and OS X\n";
my $url = "http://example.com"; 
my $status = getstore($url,"/tmp/web.html"); 
print "Result of getstore for \"$url\"\n is \"$status\" .  Success=" . is_success($status) . "\n";

print "\nThe below is successful on Windows 10 but not on OS X\n";
$url = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FqtZptibqeu4uKbv0vzinjWv5bwi8-Y2";
$status = getstore($url,"/tmp/web.html"); 
print "Result of getstore for \"$url\"\n is \"$status\" .  Success=" . is_success($status) . "\n";

print "\nPress Enter to exit";
my $ans =<stdin>;
```

Comment: Please show the code you tried, see [mcve] for more information

Comment: Are you trying to access HTTPS URLs? Do you have [LWP::Protocol::https](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Protocol::https) installed?

Comment: @virgban: Please don't share code in comments, where it's pretty much unreadable. Instead, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66326737/edit) and add the code there.

Comment: Dave Cross: Thanks for the tip on HTTPS URLs. Yes that's the URLs types I want to check for vaidity of the URL. 
The Mac only fails with using the LWP::Simple functions (get, getstore, or head) when the URL is HTTPS, 
I Tried to install  LWP::Protocol::https on the Mac but failed (It's over my head at this point). 
I've gotten a few perl modules from metacpan working a few times, always using the raw code but this https one is tough.
I do not know how to proceed and if this question is not re-opened, I may abandon this effort.

Comment: I'm guessing the two "$ cpanm" statements are commands to be entered on a Terminal window on OS X to install. If so, it appears that I do not have cpanm installed and am hesitant to install it at this point. I have previously used the raw Perl modules from metacpan rather than use their "installations" because I do not want to ask my users to go through an installation process to use my products. I have the raw code LWP::Protocol::https package/module from cpan, but I do not have the expertise to use it (no README). Can you see a way forward for my "methodology" of using the raw code?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) :

> The libwww-perl core no longer bundles protocol plugins for SSL. You
> will need to install LWP::Protocol::https separately to enable support
> for processing https-URLs.

So to access https schemed urls you need to install [LWP::Protocol::https](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Protocol::https) first, as noted by @DaveCross in the comments. Tested on macOs BigSur with perlbrew perl version 5.32.0:

```
$ cpanm LWP::Simple
$ cpanm LWP::Protocol::https
$ perl test.pl  # run your test script
The below is successful on both Windows 10 and OS X
Result of getstore for "http://example.com"
 is "200" .  Success=1

The below is successful on Windows 10 but not on OS X
Result of getstore for "https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FqtZptibqeu4uKbv0vzinjWv5bwi8-Y2"
 is "200" .  Success=1

Press Enter to exit
```

#### Note:

The reason why it might work on Windows, is that `LWP::Protocol::https` comes [preinstalled on Strawberry Perl](https://strawberryperl.com/release-notes/5.32.1.1-64bit.html) on Windows